# Sound Issues--No Output or Input Device

Tags: release-hera, sound

I'm having some trouble with the sound. In the System Settings, it says both "No Output Device" and "No Input Device," and I can't seem to hear anything.

My sound card (I think) is an Intel multimedia audio controller. I'm running eOS Hera 5.1.7 on an Asus Chromebook C434 Flip, and my kernel version is 5.4.

I just installed eOS last night and completely removed Chrome OS, so eOS is all that's on it right now. So far, everything else seems to be working, including the camera and video--I can SEE videos on YouTube, just not hear them. (And I'm guessing that the lack of input device means the microphone doesn't work either...)

Thanks in advance for any help! I'm relatively new to Linux and have not spent much time with eOS before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch OS with `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` option as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225463/18-04-no-sound-intel-sound-card-snd-hda-intel-not-working)